# Why am I getting negative current on the right loop of the Kirchhoff's circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, conventions, batteries

[image]

I have the above circuit and I calculated that the:

left loop = I<sub>1</sub>(R<sub>c</sub>+4) - I<sub>2</sub>(R<sub>c</sub>)=12

right loop = I<sub>1</sub>(R<sub>c</sub>) - I<sub>2</sub>(R<sub>c</sub>+3) = 5

I then generated numbers from 0 to 5 ohms with stepsize 0.1.

After replacing these values with the left loop to calculate the current on the left loop, I got all posative current values, but when I put it in the right loop equations, some of my current numbers turned to be negative. Does it mean the direction of the flow is wrong in the right equation? or is it due to the negative voltage on the right?

For example when I have R<sub>c</sub>=0, then current on the right is: -1.6667

This is my calculations below:

[image]

Do I keep the values obtained negative if I want to graph current vs resistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get negative current, it does not mean it is wrong. It only means that the actual current direction is in the opposite way to the assumed direction.

---

It is not clear from your schematic what is polarity of the voltage source on the right. If it is **minus** $5 \text{V}$ then your equation for the right-hand side loop has wrong polarity for the selected current direction (clockwise for both currents). The correct equations are

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
I_1 (R_c + 4) - I_2 R_c = 12 \\
I_1 R_c - I_2 (R_c + 3) = -5
\end{array}
\right.
$$

which results in

$$I_1 = \frac{36 + 17 R_c}{12 + 7 R_c} \qquad \text{and} \qquad I_2 = \frac{20 + 17 R_c}{12 + 7 R_c}$$

When you get a result like this, you should always test it against some extreme (limiting) cases:

- For $R_c = 0$ you have a short-circuit in the middle, which means two loops are completely independent. The two currents are $I_1 = 12 / (3 + 1) = 3 \text{ A}$ and $I_2 = 5 / (1 + 2) = 5/3 \text{ A}$.
- For $R_c = \infty$ you have an open-circuit in the middle, which means there is only one loop with two voltage sources. The two currents are $I_1 = I_2 = (12 + 5) / (3 + 2 + 1 + 1) = \frac{17}{7} \text{ A}$.

Comment: This complete answer to a homework-like question ([about which, see this guidance](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/44126)) contains a number of logical and arithmetic errors. The correct solution $I_2 = \frac{-20\,\mathrm V\,\Omega + 7\,\mathrm V\cdot R_c}{12\,\Omega^2 + 7\,\Omega\cdot R_c}$ does in fact have a sign change at $R_c = \frac{20}{7}\Omega$; three of the four limiting results in the answer (v4) are wrong.

Comment: @rob The schematic in the question clearly shows that the voltage source on the right is negative. Having that in mind, please point one of the *number of logical and arithmetic errors*. As for the *complete answer to a homework-like question*, I do not feel that way. The only thing I changed in OP's proposed solution is the voltage source sign, and finding the final solution is on the level of a middle school math.

Comment: A voltage source labeled with a negative number, rather than reversing the orientation of the symbol, is a nonstandard notation, practically guaranteed to confuse. The handwritten notes suggest the asker may use a raised dot rather than a baseline dot as a decimal point. If the typeface in the image is Windows Arial, the mark next to the 5 is too wide and too high to be a period, but too short to be a minus sign. It might be a hyphen, but then someone has intentionally changed its vertical alignment. The diagram is unclear to me.

Comment: @rob I agree it is unfortunate to have DC voltage sources with negative values. In my experience, a lot of these “electrical circuit simulators” have poor minus symbols. I am almost certain that the voltage source on the right is negative $5 \text{V}$. Also, the OP uses number $5$ in his solution and not $0.5$, which also makes me believe the symbol is actually a minus sign.

Comment: @rob "A voltage source labeled with a negative number, rather than reversing the orientation of the symbol, is a nonstandard notation": There's nothing _nonstandard_ in a voltage source labelled with a negative value. It might be confusing for a beginner, but not for anyone with a minimum of expertise in circuit theory. A negative _value_ (not number) just means that the actual polarity is the opposite of the reference polarity specified by the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Marko Gulin said, a negative number doesn't mean its wrong, it just means the direction of the loop current you chose is opposite to the actual direction of the loop current.

More importantly, you should show the direction of the loop currents that your equations are based on so that we don't have to take the time to figure out if your loop equations are correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just updated it

Answer (score -1):

In the limit $R_\text{C}\to\infty$, this becomes a single-loop circuit where the 12V source pushes current the “wrong way” through the 5V source. This is one type of battery charger.

In the limit $R_\text{C}\to 0$, you have two independent circuits which are both sending current through the same conducting segment.  This is also a common configuration for real circuits; we frequently call the shared segment “the ground.”

Between your electronic diagram, your handwritten notes, and your equation, I can’t tell whether the constant voltage on the right is $V_2 = \rm 5\,V$, or $V_2 = \rm -5\,V$, or $V_2 = \rm 0.5\,V$.  If it’s actually negative, and you’ve written a negative value instead of putting the battery symbol’s long lines on the bottom, you are suffering for no good reason.  If it’s positive, the equation in your question (v3) contains at least one sign error.

Comment: can nominal resistances be combined into one? or it should be calculated for each loop?

Comment: I don’t quite know what you mean “combined into one.” Go around the loop in the direction of your current, compute the voltage drop (or rise) across each element, and add them up to zero total voltage change around the loop. Resistors with the same current will get “lumped” together, like your $3\Omega$ and $1\Omega$ resistors, because multiplication is distributive and algebra is your friend. Resistors with different currents do not get “lumped” together.